# El Capitan install fails without error message

Tags: macos, imac, install

Bought a used iMac supposedly tested by the folks at the Goodwill store electronics group.  Worked OK for me for a long time, and did one macOS upgrade.

But after leaving it off for a few months, I powered it up and got the install menu.

Two tries to install (El Capitan) went as follows:

- Click "Continue"
- Accept conditions
- Select main drive partition
- Click "Install"
- Watch the "minutes remaining" shrink and the progress bar grow
- screen goes black; goes to sleep
- tap space bar; it wakes up and displays the install utilities menu again.

If I exit install utilities, I get asked to select a startup disk—from an **empty** list.

Any remedy other than paying someone for a hardware repair?

Hopefully I didn't break anything trying to photograph the label under the stand.  Too small to read any other way.  Anyway, it seems to be a Mac Core 2 Duo 2.4GHz 20-Inch, 2007-2008.

UPDATE: Several web pages, including one on Apple.com, said I needed to reset the iMac's clock to close to the time El Capitan was released.  But that didn't change anything.  Ran first aid with disk utility.  It said there was nothing wrong with the system volume or the recovery volume.  BUT, after that each install attempt got an immediate "something went wrong" whereas before it would take thirty minutes acting like it was installing.

Finally managed to create a bootable El Capitan installer (using the same Apple-provided method that had failed several times before).  Ran that and got a working iMac again.

Comment: How about the year and screen size? Or get a number off the bottom. See [Identify your iMac model](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201634)

Comment: You could try using a USB installer. At least then you take away to possibility the problem is with downloading the operating system.

Comment: I don't think I have an installer for El Capitan or earlier.  I believe that's the last one it can support.  Haven't had much success with making installers on newer machines.

Comment: It’s booting recovery so, it’s getting it from somewhere.  Try Internet recovery, hold `Cmd-Opt-R` while powering up.   2010 and later models supported this.  Does this iMac have a square or tapered body?

Comment: I have 2006, 2007, 2011 and 2013 iMacs. The 2006 is dead. 2007 is flakey. Installed El Capitan on it and somedays the Mac boots and other days the Mac stops before completely booting. Tried Ubuntu and Windows with the same problems. There is no pattern. I guess the computer just got old. No problems with the 2011 and 2013. If fact I am using the 2011 right now.

Comment: WGroleau: Did all six sides include the bottom of the stand?

Comment: The _stand_.  Hmm.  I've never seen one there, but it's worth checking.  Not easy to do in that cluttered room.

Comment: So, it's 2007-2008 so Cmd-Ope-R probably won't work.  But it can't hurt.  Or, I might be able to use a 2012 MBP to put a bootable El Capitan on an external drive.